# Get list of files for asp.net web app returning not a valid virtual path

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get a list of files in a folder on the filesystem in my .net web app. When I run the app, I am getting an error that says that the directory "is not a valid virtual path". How do I get this to return files, that are in my WebApp's directory (they are located in {webapp root}\docs\custFiles).

```
try
{
    List<string> custFiles = new List<string>();
    StringBuilder dir = new StringBuilder(@"~\docs\custFiles\");
    dir.Append(custNo + @"\");
    string directory = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(dir.ToString());
    bool IsExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(directory);
    if (!IsExists)
    {
        string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(directory);
        custFiles = (fileList.ToList());
    }

    return custFiles;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: You're calling mappath twice

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
bool IsExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(directory));
```

As you've already built the directory name here:

```
string directory = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(dir.ToString());
```

You can just use the Exists call without Server.MapPath:

```
bool IsExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(directory);
```

Comment: I'm also assuming that the custNo folder from (dir.Append(custNo + @"\");) exists.

Answer (score 0):

Well, It seems problem with virtual path you are passing. Instead that try this.

```
String directory=Server.MapPath("~/docs/custFiles");
if(System.IO.Directory.Exists(directory))
{
   //do your coding..
}
```